# .bashrc doesn't get executed

Tags: bash, rhel, bashrc

I have a user (non-root) which has a `~/.bashrc` file with some aliases in it.

But it doesn't look like the file is executed at log in time. If I do `source ~/.bashrc` then it does what it's supposed to. But isn't `~/.bashrc` supposed to be executed every time I log in?

Permissions are set to 644 (same as my root's `.bashrc`, which works fine). File is owned by the user in question.

Comment: This is one of the several annoyances ksh users experience when dealing with bash. ksh sources automatically .kshrc in a login shell but bash doesn't source .bashrc in  the same context. You have to do it explicitly.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`~/.bashrc` is for **non-login** interactive shells.  Login shells source `~/.bash_profile` (or `~/.bash_login` or `~/.profile`).  Sourcing your `~/.bashrc` there will allow you to have common settings.

Comment: Or [source `.bash_profile` from `.bashrc`](https://github.com/janmoesen/tilde/blob/ac0be9e5a5/.bashrc), which might make sense when you primarily use interactive shells.

Comment: I've felt the need to do things for login shells that weren't done for interactive non login one, never the reverse.

Comment: Hence "*might* make sense": I know it can come across as backwards. :-)

Comment: Is it possible to configure a redhat system to ignore .bashrc when running non-interactive jobs? I use a cluster that seems to actually use the .bash_profile (mine then loads the .bashrc). Without the .bash_profile, the jobs can't find the stuff that I've added to the PATH in the rc file